# Java Recursion: Example

Tags: java, recursion

I am aware of how [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) works, i.e:

`method calls itself until it reaches a base case then it can start solving its problem.`

In this code example is a method or removing flowers from a vase.

I have added a trace statement to be able to see how many flowers are in the vase after every call. However the output leaves 7 flowers in the vase. I am confused as to why?

Code:

```
public static void emptyVase( int flowersInVase ) {
    if( flowersInVase > 0 ) {
    // take one flower and
        emptyVase( flowersInVase - 1 ) ;

        System.out.println(flowersInVase);


    } else {
           // the vase is empty, nothing to do

    }
}
```

Invoking the method:

```
public class RecursionPractice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        emptyVase(7);    
    }
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Comment: Java passes arguments Call-by-Value.

Comment: you need to pass variable flowersInVase by reference to reflect the changes

Comment: @RNI2013 In simple words: nobody will ever see what `emptyVase()` did to `flowersInVase`.

Comment: @RNI2013 Are you now referring to the order of the prints? If this is a concern swap the System.out.println() and emptyVase() line.

Comment: I am basically wondering why the vase is not empty at the end of the call?

Answer (score 10):

In recursion the order of the calls is very important! You can understand better your own example when you *unroll* it. It will look like this:

```
// step 1
// flowerInVase is greater than 7, so the first thing to do is call the function again! 
// Note that the System.out.println is NOT yet reached because of the execution of the function!
// call emptyVse(7 - 1), the *stack* has *remembered* to the current value of *floweInVase* => 7
emptyVase(7); 
// step 2
emptyVase(6);
// condition is *true* yet again, so the same rules as above apply
// current *remembered* value of `floweInVase` is 6
// step 3
emptyVase(5);
// and so on ... until `flowerInVase` is 0 ... now ...
```

Now the *stack* looks like this:

```
emptyVase(7)
    emptyVase(6)
        emptyVase(5)
            emptyVase(4)
                emptyVase(3)
                    emptyVase(2)
                        emptyVase(1)
                            emptyVase(0) 
                                -> nothing to do, recursion is stopped.
                                -> so go back to previous 
                                -> *stack frame* which is 1
                        System.out.println(1);
                    System.out.println(2);
                System.out.println(3);
            System.out.println(4);
        System.out.println(5);
    System.out.println(6);
System.out.println(7);
```

In *stack frame* for `emptyVase(1)` the function execution is done, so print the current `flowerInVase` which is **1**. Go back to the previous *stack frame*, every time print the *currently stored variable* until the last *stack frame* is reached.

And that is why the order is reverse! That is also why if you change the order of the print and the function execution it will look as expected.

```
public static void emptyVase( int flowersInVase ) {
    // if there is a flower to take from the vase
    if( flowersInVase > 0 ) {
        // print the count of flowers BEFORE one is taken!
        System.out.println(flowersInVase);
        // take one flower and put it aside
        emptyVase( flowersInVase - 1 ) ;
    } else {
           // the vase is empty, nothing to do
           System.out.println(flowersInVase);
           // print 0!
    }
}
```

This will produce:

```
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

The *vase* is actually empty, but because your condition is `flowerInVase > 0`, this means when the last *call* is made with `emptyVase(0)` the *else* part is taken and you don't print there the value of the counter. Add a print there and you will see an *empty vase*.

Your approach (and the example) for understanding recursion is good. I think the important thing to notice in your example is the fact, that the recursive call **interrupts** the current function call and starts a new one (executes the same function again), but the previous call is *remembered* and once the new call is done, the *flow* continues from where it was interrupted!

You could imagine every *recursive call* as a creation of a *box in a box*:

```
|-------------------------------|
|--- emptyVase(7)           --- |
|                               |
|   |--- emptyVase(6)       ---||
|   |                          ||
|   |   |--- emptyVase(5)   ---||
|   |   |                      ||
|   |   |   |... and so on     ||
|   |   |   |---emptyVase(0)---||
|   |   |   | S.out.println(0) ||
|   |   |   |------------------||
|   |   |----------------------||
|   |   System.out.println(6)  ||
|   |--------------------------||
|   System.out.println(7);     ||
|-------------------------------|
```

The **deeper** the recursion, the more boxes you have.

This is also where the problem is. Recursion is pretty expensive in terms of memory allocation and because the computers have a finite amount of memory, if the recursion creates *too many* boxes, the execution of the program *reaches the maximum allowed count of boxes = stack frames* and says *stack overflow*. Be aware that my explanation is a very basic one. For a thorough explanation of the so called *call stack* have a look at this [Wikipedia article - Call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_frame#Structure).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am just having a hard time understanding recursion

Answer (score 1):

Each call to `emptyVase()` will print a `flowersInVase` value , so  basicly you will call `System.out.println()` 7 times. The first print '1' is for the last call to `emptyVase()`, the second one '2' is for the before last one and so again .The last one '7' is for the first call to `emptyVase()` witch was realy 7 flower in the vase.

Comment: Thank you, so this is basiaclly the method solving itself after it has reached the base case?

Comment: That explains the output; but can you add a solution as well?

Comment: replace your code with ` System.out.println(flowersInVase[0]); emptyVase( flowersInVase[0]-- ) ;       ` (switch print and emptyVase() call)

Answer (score 0):

Nopes. The method is fine. It will keep on removing one flower at a time from the vase till the vase is empty. If you are expecting the below output(assuming that the method is called with `flowersInVase` to be 10 ):

`10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1`

Then you should write `System.out.println(flowersInVase); emptyVase( flowersInVase - 1 );` instead of `emptyVase( flowersInVase - 1 ); System.out.println(flowersInVase);`

Answer (score 0):

try it with an int[] instead (only copy and pasted your code and substituted the array for the int -- you'll have to verify it works)

```
public static void emptyVase( int[] flowersInVase ) {
      if( flowersInVase[0] > 0 ) {
       // take one flower and
        emptyVase( flowersInVase[0]-- ) ;

        System.out.println(flowersInVase[0]);

      } 
    }
```

...

```
public class RecursionPractice {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    emptyVase(new int[]{7});

}
```

The reason it won't work with a primitive `int` is because only the *value* of the int is passed, not a reference to the memory location holding the value, which is what you need to have in order to have the change reflected in all method invocations.

Answer (score -1):

```
Print the flowersInVase before the recursive call. That will solve your confusion like below.

public static void emptyVase( int flowersInVase ) {
          if( flowersInVase > 0 ) {
           // take one flower and


            System.out.println(flowersInVase);  // **** Moved the print Here **********


            emptyVase( flowersInVase - 1 ) ;




          } else {
           // the vase is empty, nothing to do
              System.out.println("Hurray It's empty now..");
          }
        }



public class RecursionPractice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        emptyVase(7);
    }
```